# Python: Regular expression match does not end properly

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match regular expression in Python.

I want to match string like `\u01234string`, or `string\u01234string` or `string\u01234`.

My solution is `\\u\d+\D+(,|\s|\D+)`.

Click https://regex101.com/r/gmWALn/1  for my expression and sample text.

The problem: No matter what I try, the match refuses to end. If I add `$`, then it wouldn't match anything.

[image]

In this example, `\u0130stanbul` and `Regi\u00f3n`.

Comment: What's your expected match?

Answer (score 0):

if your string is always going to have a unicode char in it like you're shown above, this regex works:

```
\w*(\\u\w+)+
```

tested successfully here: http://pythex.org/

Comment: I checked. It successfully matched the second one, but missed the first one in the example. https://regex101.com/r/gmWALn/4

Comment: sorry, missed one this. try this instead -- it just matched both on your regex.com link you sent:

Comment: \w*(\\u\w+)+

notice the parentheses.

Comment: I checked again. It still only matched the first one. Thank you though.

Comment: sorry, i think i edited my original regex. this worked for me and it matches both of your strings: 

https://regex101.com/r/gmWALn/5  

sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`\u00f3` isn't a literal slash, a "u", and hexadecimal characters. It's only a representation of the unicode character U+00F3 `ó` (LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE).

So, if you want to match it, use the pattern: `ur'ó'`

Comment: There are hundreds of different unicode. Is there a way to match them all, rather then matching one?

Comment: @JohnHass: What is your goal? Why do you want to match them? to do what? Other thing, your string seems to be a JSON string, start to use a JSON parser first.

Comment: Goal in this question: find all unicode pharses, like `\u0130stanbul` and `Regi\u00f3n` in a large file by regular expression. Ultimate goal: replace all unicode pharses, like `\u0130stanbul` and `Regi\u00f3n` in a large file to no-tip-top words.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to remove all accent, tip-top on the alphabet. For example, cliché to cliche.

Comment: First decode the json string, then build a recursive function to change each values using `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode`. You can also, use `unidecode` in the raw string without decoding the json string.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing. But I am not sure why it is recursive. I am trying to scan line by line.

Comment: @JohnHass: and for what reason you want to change all accented characters to ascii?

Comment: It is required by an existing database table. I have no other choices.